# How can I synchronize old notes with an email account on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, notes.app

I had hundreds of notes on my iPhone before I upgraded to OS 4.0. Now there is the new feature which allows me to sync the notes with an email account. I added my email account, but rather than sync all of my existing notes, it created a new folder in the Notes application.

How can I transfer notes from my old folder "On My iPhone" to my new one that is synced to an email account.

I'm looking for a method which doesn't require syncing to the computer, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syncing the notes to your computer, then moving the notes to your email notes and letting it sync back to the phone would be the easiest.

Without syncing you could email each note to yourself by clicking the envelope icon at the bottom of each note. Then turn it into a note in your email account, of course this would take a long time but you wouldn't have to sync with your computer.