# Where do the Notes associated with Gmail accounts get synced to on iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, data-synchronization, gmail, notes.app

I noticed that notes, like Calendars, get synced with a Gmail account on the iPod touch.

But where do they get synced to? Where can I access them online?

Comment: I changed the tag from `[notes]` to `[notes.app]` as (imo) there are just too many things called "Notes" that shouldn't all share one tag.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between syncing with iTunes and over the air sync.

If you set up your Gmail account to use over the air sync then when you open up the Notes app (on the iPod), you should notice a back button on the top left that allows you to change which account you use for notes. If you choose your Gmail account and start creating notes, you will start seeing them appear in your Gmail account, under the "Notes" label. This sync happens automatically once you press the "done" button on each note (as long as you have an internet connection).

This has nothing to do with iTunes sync.

You will only see notes that you create under this account in Gmail. You will not see all of your old notes. For that, see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/how-can-i-synchronize-old-notes-with-an-email-account-on-the-iphone).

Comment: I believe this is the right answer. Did you get it working, @leeand00? Btw, related useful screenshots in [this blog post](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/06/save-iphone-notes-to-gmail-account.html).

Answer (score 1):

It syncs the notes from the Notes application on your iOS device to the Notes using a special mailbox on the Mail Accounts you have enabled (eg. your Gmail account here). They should appear in the Notes section in Mail.app on your Mac or in a label called "Notes" on Gmail.

Comment: hmm...I have a label in my gmail account that Reads "Notes", but I have not notes, even after syncing.  Is there something else that I have to do?

Comment: you probably don't see the notes since they were created on the phone (and stayed that way), rather than getting marked being associated with the gmail account. This happens in many other apps as well, including contacts.

Answer (score 1):

add notes to your email address
ex : if your email is sam@gmail.com just type sam+notes@gmail.com and send it
then you can filter it in your inbox with label NOTES